# How to tile a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, catiledlayer

I need to use tiles with a UIWebview to improve the rendering and scrolling of the content.

I tried to find some info in Google but it seems that there are no examples or technical info about this subject. I am doing some test with CATiledLayer class without luck...

Basically, I want to replicate the same that Mobile Safari does with the content of a website. You can see how Safari makes tiles when you see the checkered background.

Any help will be very welcome!

Thanks in advance,
Franky

Comment: Have you found how to implement this correctly? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue has been "handled" on another question.  Doesn't look possible, or at least, reasonable (Apple even weighed in):

[How to improve UIWebView scrolling performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060248/how-to-improve-uiwebview-scrolling-performance)